# How to solve $y'+4y=3e^t+t$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I have been trying to solve a differential equation.

The goal is to give a general solution to it.

I have to solve this: $y'+4y=3e^t+t$

[solving the homogeneous solution](https://i.stack.imgur.com/z73mL.jpg)

[solving the particular solution 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AHnQw.jpg)

[solving the second particular solution 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PzlKc.jpg)

But how did the $- \frac{1}{16}$ comes there?

I think I made a mistake during the solving process...

Comment: Check to make sure you 2nd particular solution solves the ODE correctly.

Comment: $y_{par2} =Ct+\color{red}{D}$

Answer (score 1):

Your approach $y_{\text{p}}(t) = Ct$ does not lead you to a particular solution since $C + 4Ct = t$ is not fulfilled for $C = 1/4$. You should try $y_{\text{p}} = Ct + D$, then you get

$$C + 4 (Ct + D) = t,$$

which leads you to $(C, D) = (1/4, - 1/16)$.

Answer (score 1):

[image: Solution to second particular solution]

I see it and adjusted the answer of the 2nd particular solution.

Comment: Yes, you got it!